# If $\sum {a_n}$ converges, does $\sum {o(a_n)}$ converges as well?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Suppose we have an **arbitrary** sequence $a_n$. And assume that it's series

$$
\sum a_n
$$
converges **conditionally.** Does that mean that the series
$$
\sum b_n
$$
also converges if $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} b_n/a_n=0$ ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any thoughts on the problem? As a hint, consider a series of the form $a_n=(-1)^n\alpha_n$ where $\sum_n\alpha_n$ diverges, and see if you can find a way of 'picking out' essentially just the positive terms of $a_n$ (you'll need something a bit smaller, but that can easily be done)...

Comment: Yes, I have a little bit. You know, if $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely, then of course $\sum{b_n}$ converges absolutely as well, since $|b_n| < |a_n|$ for sufficiently large $n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false in general, take $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\log n}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$, then $\frac{b_n}{a_n}=(-1)^n\frac{\log n}{n}\rightarrow 0$, $\sum a_n$ converges but $\sum b_n$ diverges.